# Java EE Filter and Listener

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

If I implement a `Filter` that before the request is processed it prints to the browser the date/time like this:

```
@WebServlet(name = "TimedServlet",
urlPatterns =
{
    "/timed_servlet"
}, initParams =
{
    @WebInitParam(name = "prod", value = "true")
})
class TimedServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    @WebFilter(filterName = "Time_F",
    urlPatterns =
    {
        "/timed_servlet"
    })
    private class Time_F implements Filter
    {
        private FilterConfig fc;

        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException
        {
            fc = filterConfig;
        }

        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
        {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat sd_f = new SimpleDateFormat();

            response.getWriter().println(sd_f.format(cal));

            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

        public void destroy()
        {
            fc = null;
        }
    }

    protected void doRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter())
        {

            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet ---</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("PROD");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        doRequest(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        doRequest(request, response);
    }

    public String getServletInfo()
    {
        return "...";
    }
}
```

nothing is showed in the browser but only the servlet output!

And If I want to process a `ServletRequestListener` how can I access a response object so I can
show some info to the user?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `response.getWriter().flush()` right after you write your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to invoke [`FilterChain#doFilter()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/FilterChain.html#doFilter%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) to let the request go to the servlet/JSP. Otherwise you're plain blocking the initial request.

```
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

As to your second question, no there the [`ServletRequestListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequestListener.html) is not designed for.

---

Unrelated to the concrete problem, please keep in mind that a `Filter` is not necessarily the right place to write something to the response. This way the Servlet/JSP has no chance anymore to control/change the response as per business requirements and/or in case of exceptions. You'll risk ending up with `IllegalStateException`s in the server logs. If you want to print the date in all pages, you have to do it in the JSP side. To achieve this, store the date as a request attribute instead:

```
String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
request.setAttribute("timestamp", timestamp);
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

and then display it in JSP as follows

```
${timestamp}
```

*(you can also just store the `new Date()` and use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<fmt:formatDate>` to format the date)*

Comment: Unfortunately also calling that statement the output is not showed to the browser.

Comment: Read the server logs. Do you see an `IllegalStateException`? Remove the line from the filter which writes to the response.

Comment: Is it not the case that the output is written to the browser but because it's written outside the <html></html> block it won't be rendered by the browser? have you tried to view the source file in the browser and see if that is the case?

Comment: @Liv: can also, but that's browser dependent. After all, the OP is going about this totally wrong. The presentation needs to be done in the JSP.

Comment: @BalusC, no exception into server log.

Comment: Then the problem lies somewhere else than in the information provided as far in the question and comments. Please note that I updated the answer with an example how it should really be done.

Comment: @Liv the output is all empty.

Comment: @Balusc, strange because if I run the servlet its output is showed. I submit into the question all the code... wait a moment...

Comment: How did you run the servlet then? It listens on the same `urlPattern`, right? Or did you turn off the `@WebFilter`?

Comment: @BalusC, I've submitted all the code. So you can test it. Thanks.

Comment: Huh? Did you really nest the `Filter` inside the `HttpServlet`? Put it in its own class. Your servlet code is also open for optimization by the way, but that's another story.

Comment: Then the problem lies somewhere else. Run a debugger. What line of code get executed and what not. Or just redo the servlet/filter tutorials. At the bottom of our wiki pages you can find references http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info

Comment: Then the URL is wrong or the filter class/mapping/annotation is wrong. Are you sure you have put the filter in a standalone public class in a package? And that you have removed the nested filter class from the servlet as is shown in your current question code?

Comment: Ok I found the problem! First I must define a filter class in a standalone file... public class F implements Filter. After the filter is invoked and I found an error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date so I correct also this and all work. Thanks for your HELP :)